# Select rows from a pandas dataframe where two columns match list of pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a boolean mask (or list of indices) from a dataframe to indicate where multiple columns match some combinations in a list. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alice', 'bob'    , 'charlie'  , 'dave' , 'dave'], 
                   'B': ['andy' , 'bridget', 'charlotte', 'diana', 'andy'], 
                   'C': ['some' , 'other'  , 'stuff'    , 'here' , '!' ]})

pairs = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alice', 'dave'],
                      'B': ['andy' , 'diana']})
```

My desired output is either

```
[True, False, False, True, False]
```

or

```
[0, 3]
```

Critically, I **don't** want to return row index 4 i.e. `['dave', 'andy', '!']`. I can achieve what I want by converting back to lists...but this feels like a long way round and I imagine there's a 'pandas' way to do this!

```
df_list = df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()
pairs_list = pairs.values.tolist()
[idx for idx, row in enumerate(df_list) if row in pairs_list]
```

Comment: Edited - thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could perform a `outer` type merge with `indicator=True` param and test whether `_merge` `column == 'both'`:

```
In [97]:
merged = df.merge(pairs, how='outer', indicator=True)
merged[merged['_merge'] =='both'].index

Out[97]:
Int64Index([0, 3], dtype='int64')
```

To get a boolean `Series`:

```
In [98]:
merged['_merge'] =='both'

Out[98]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: _merge, dtype: bool
```

the merged df looks like this:

```
In [99]:
merged

Out[99]:
         A          B      C     _merge
0    alice       andy   some       both
1      bob    bridget  other  left_only
2  charlie  charlotte  stuff  left_only
3     dave      diana   here       both
4     dave       andy      !  left_only
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that, if you want to use `msk = merged['_merge'] == 'both'` as a mask for a pandas DataFrame (e.g. df.ix[msk]) or a numpy array (e.g. df[msk, :]), you need to extract the boolean numpy array i.e. make `msk = (merged['_merge'] =='both').values`

Comment: it'll fail whenever you try to use a boolean mask Series with a df that is not the shape or has the same index values

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment @EdChum. I'm struggling when using this to mask another dataframe with the same order as df. Does the merge reorder and thus render the mask useless for this purpose?

Comment: But the merged df will have more rows than the original dfs and the index values will not necessarily be present in either df or be the same length

Comment: Ok...I think I'll need to come back to this later and construct a better example! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kungfujam - This worked fine for me by using the merged as mask without converting to numpy values.  Great solution EdChum, undervoted in my opinion.